# Trying to get <img> tags from text with subString and indexOf

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

So I got a variable called text and in there are HTML entities.
My code is working fine, because I'm getting the whole `<img ...>` tag.
But this is the problem sometimes there are more then 1 `<img>` tag.
Now my question is how do I get all of those `<img>` tags, I was thinking about something like adding `/g` at the end of indexof, but that wasn't a success.

This is what I have so far:

```
var images = text.substring((text.indexOf("<img")), ((text.indexOf("/>")) + 2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** with regex **[`<img[^>]*\/?>`](https://regex101.com/r/bU6pP2/1)**

```js
var text = `
<img src="#" />
<img src="sss.jpg" />
`;

var images = text.match(/<img[^>]*\/?>/g);

console.log(images);
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/bU6pP2/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thank you, I seriously couldn't think of anything better then this. Your answer is just EXACTLY what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Make `text` string a jQuery object

```
$(text)
```

Find all the `img` using

```
$(text).find('img').addBack('img')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is along these lines

```
 var tags = [];
 var re = /<img?([^/>]+)?/>/g, match;
 while(match = re.exec(text)) {
     tags.push(match[0]);
 }
```

tags would then contain all the found image tags.